# How to set report parameters when the data source is multiple csv files?

Tags: csv, datasource, birt

I am using BIRT reporting tool, and the data source is multiple csv files. How can I set report parameters?

Employee sales information is stored in sale. csv, and employee information with dates greater than 2015-03-02 needs to be queried based on input parameter.

sale.csv data is as follows：

```
userName,date,saleValue,saleCount
Rachel,2015-3-1,4500,9
Rachel,2015-3-3,8700,4
Tom,2015-3-2,3000,8
Tom,2015-3-3,5000,7
Tom,2015-3-4,6000,12
John,2015-3-2,4000,3
John,2015-3-2,4300,9
John,2015-3-4,4800,4
```

Comment: Are you implementing the reporting logic or are you intending to use a tool of some kind?

Comment: I am wondering if there is a simple tool to solve the problem.